# UltraATA laptop drive need replaced...what format to use?

Tags: laptop, sata

I've admittedly been out of IT for TOO long, and dont' have this probably simple answer in my brain.

I have a Gateway MX6453 that the Seagate UltraATA-100 drive has bad sectors, won't boot to OS. Want to clone and replace drive.

Can I replace with an SATA drive, or will connectors be too different for the enclosure the current drive is in?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot plug in a SATA drive to an ATA connection. They make adapters but I do not think there will be space for it within the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ultra-ATA / ATA-100 is a variant of Parallel ATA (PATA, the old 40/80 wire ribbon cables). You cannot use a SATA drive to replace this unit without some kind of adapter (and as far as I know these are not made for laptop drives) -- Your best bet is to source a PATA/ATA-100 drive.